# Debug assertion failed at fread()

Tags: c

The size of the test.bin is 7,01,760 bytes. I am trying to read date from this file as "short" in a buffer bufferPointer.

```
short * bufferPointer=NULL; 
// ==> ANSWER WAS ADDING: bufferPointer = ( short*)malloc(350880); <==
FILE *fp=fopen(" test.bin","rb");
fread(bufferPointer,sizeof(short),350880 ,fp); 
fclose(fp);
```

I am getting Debug Assertion Failed at fread(). Why?

MSVC2010, Windows-7-32 bit

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should first allocate sufficient amount of memory to the `bufferPointer` by using `malloc`. Then you can use `fread` to read from the file into that buffer.

Answer (score 6):

You allocated 350880 bytes for your buffer but tried to read 350880 shorts. Try

```
bufferPointer = malloc(350880 * sizeof *bufferPointer);
```

(Note that casting malloc isn't necessary, and is frowned upon because it can hide bugs.)

You should also check your malloc, fopen, and fread calls for errors.

Answer (score 1):

sgar91 is correct. Just try:

```
short * bufferPointer = (short *)malloc(350880*sizeof(short)); 
if (bufferPointer == NULL)
{
  // TODO: error handling
}

FILE *fp = fopen("test.bin", "rb");
if (fp == NULL)
{
  // TODO: error handling
}

fread(bufferPointer, sizeof(short), 350880, fp); 
fclose(fp);
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
short bufferPointer[350880]; 
FILE *fp=fopen("test.bin","rb");
fread(bufferPointer,sizeof(short),350880 ,fp); 
fclose(fp);
```

Few things here

1) You cannot use a pointer directly in this way. Either statically allocate memory like above or use malloc to allocate dynamically

2) There is a space in the beginning in the string " test.bin". Remove the leading space.

3) Even if the above works, it may not give you meaningful results. `fread` reads stuff which has been written by `fwrite`. i.e. was the file creating using `fwrite` writing `short`s? If not, what you read may make no sense.

Comment: shouldn't he allocate memory?