# Debug Assertion Failed Buffer != NULL

Tags: c++, c, visual-studio-2013, wav

Hello I got a college project to read Wav file with any Language possible so i chose C/C++ i think i got everything right but 1 thing  i have been working on 
the c project i always get this msg   "Buffer != NULL"

the full code :

```
int main (){
    //char id[10];
    FILE *wav;
    wav=fopen("sound.wav","rb");

    if(wav){
        BYTE wav_id[5], *sound_buffer;      
        DWORD size;

        short format_tag, channels, block_align, bits_per_sample;
        DWORD format_length, sample_rate, avg_bytes_sec,datasize,i;

        fread(&wav_id,sizeof(BYTE),4,wav);
        wav_id[sizeof(BYTE)+3]=0;   

        if (!memcmp(&wav_id,"RIFF",4)) {
            fread(&size,sizeof(DWORD),1,wav);
            fread(&wav_id,sizeof(BYTE),4,wav); 
            if (!memcmp(&wav_id,"WAVE",4)) { //this is probably a wave file since it contained "WAVE" 

                fread(&wav_id,sizeof(BYTE),4,wav); //read in 4 bytes "fmt "; 
                fread(&format_length,sizeof(DWORD),1,wav);
                fread(&format_tag, sizeof(short), 1, wav); 
                fread(&channels, sizeof(short),1,wav); 
                fread(&sample_rate, sizeof(DWORD), 1, wav); 
                fread(&avg_bytes_sec, sizeof(short), 1, wav); 
                fread(&block_align, sizeof(short), 1, wav); 
                fread(&bits_per_sample, sizeof(short), 1, wav); 
                fread(&wav_id, sizeof(BYTE), 4, wav); //read in 'data' 
                fread(&datasize, sizeof(DWORD), 1, wav); //how many bytes of sound data we 
                sound_buffer=(BYTE *)malloc(sizeof(BYTE) * datasize);
                fread(sound_buffer, sizeof(BYTE), datasize, wav);  // i trace the problem to this line the whole above code seems to run smooth 
            }
            cout << "\n The file is Riff but it's not a wav file"<<endl;
        }
        else {
            cout <<"\nNOT a Wav File\n"<<endl;}

        }
    else {
        cout <<"\nFile wasn't opened\n"<<endl;
    }

    system("pause");
}
```

Comment: You should read the error message again, it's very clear. It shoudl also contain the line number the error is on, so it's very easy to find. And how can you get an assertion error if the program doesn't even build? Also, the assertion error and the build error are two different and separate problems, so you should probably be having two questions, not mix them together in one.

Comment: You're going to have to give more details than that.  What lines are generating the compile error?  C and C++ are not the same language, switching the project from one to the other is not always trivial.

Comment: it says line 147 while my code is only 66 lines , and i know where the problem is but i can't figure it out how to solve it

Comment: i got 2 projects the assert error occurs when compiling the c project

Comment: i did use it , but it also didn't work correctly it came up with trash

Comment: Besides, you have [*undefined behavior*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior) in your code, as `wav_id` isn't a proper zero-terminated string. That means the `strcmp` function will go beyond the end of the `wav_id` array. And I so hope that `wav_id` is an array, or you have more (possibly two cases of) undefined behavior when passing a pointer to `wav_id` when reading.

Comment: Also note that C++ have stricter type-checking rules than C, which is why code that compiles without errors by a C compiler might give compilation errors when compiled as C++ code.

Comment: @qwr I think you mean `memcmp` and not `memcpy`?

Comment: Perhaps you could show what wav_id is, and where it originates

Comment: //memcpy(id,wav_id,sizeof(BYTE));  no i already used it then when i got trash i had to round "BYTE wav_id[4]" to 
" BYTE wav_id[5]  wav_id[sizeof(BYTE)+3]=0; " to avoid trash by fread

Comment: i will post all the definitions gmme a second

Comment: I think I'd be using an unsigned 4 byte integer for IDs

Comment: if u mean wav_id int is not an option because  i am reading the first 4 bytes of the file which are "RIFF"

Comment: It is an option for sure. You just need a different mindset.

Comment: *Please leave the second problem aside* you say. Well, please ask one question at a time. If you spent more time making a good question you'd get better help and fewer downvotes.

Comment: well my bad sorry but i solved the second problem can u please help with the first one ?

Comment: `c project i always get this msg "Buffer != NULL"` in which code you are getting this problem!

Comment: there is only one code the one in the post

Comment: Please show us how to produce this error

Comment: @DavidHeffernan i just go across the code with the debugger and the problem pops on the line shown in the question

Comment: see this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13356036/debug-assertion-failed-at-fread

Comment: sound_buffer , but when it pops up it opens fread.c and it breaks on this line " _VALIDATE_RETURN((buffer != NULL), EINVAL, 0); "

Comment: @qwr yeah i saw it already before asking the question but i already used malloc

Comment: @BishoyM if you looked well you found answer. there are proper ways how to deal with it. for example see Fermat2357 answer

Comment: You called malloc, but it returned NULL

Comment: well i looked well and i did check and i know it returns null after David told me but i wont be here if i could handle it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is easier to treat the WAVE audio IDs as integers. Say `uint32_t`. Then you can consult an ASCII table to define some constants:

```
const uint32_t RIFF_ID = 0x46464952;
```

Remembering that WAVE audio is a little endian format.

And then you can read directly into `uint32_t` variables and compare simply with `==`.

---

Regarding the other problem, the assertion failure in `fread`, most likely `datasize` is a very large valiue and the call to `malloc` fails, returning `NULL`. When you pass `NULL` as the buffer for `fread`, the debug version of the CRT detects that problem.  Add some error checking. It is a mistake to call `malloc` without checking the return value for an error.

Comment: i didn't know that i will search for it thx

Comment: yeah i checked it and it returns null , but how i can handle this ?

Comment: I guess you are reading the header wrong. Or the WAVE file is invalid.

Comment: well anyway thanks i will go my own from here thx again

Answer (score 1):

AS your error shows-

```
Error 2 error C2664: 'strcmp' : cannot convert parameter 1 from 'BYTE [5]' to 'const char *'
```

You cant pass `BYTE [5]` data types to string compare function. It is invalid against the prototype. Syntax is-

```
int strcmp(const char *s1, const char *s2);
```

Your both arguments must be strings!

But you are passing `wav_id` to `strcmp`. i think it is not a string-

```
strcmp(wav_id,"RIFF") // problem 
strcmp(wav_id,"WAVE") // problem
```

---

Else you can use `memcmp` to compare to memory locations. Prototype is-

```
int memcmp(const void *s1, const void *s2, size_t n);
```

Both arguments are `void *`, so you can pass any type of pointer this function!

Try the following changes-

```
if (!memcmp(&wav_id,"RIFF",4)) {
    fread(&size,sizeof(DWORD),1,wav);
    fread(&wav_id,sizeof(BYTE),4,wav); 
    if (!memcmp(&wav_id,"WAVE",4)) 
... }
```

Comment: `BYTE` is probably a typedef for `unsigned char`, so chances are you can use `memcmp` to accomplish this instead.

Comment: am sorry MR but i actually know that , i need a way to get around it coz i tried everything casting , coping everything and nothing happened

Comment: @BishoyM if you know that, why are you writing strcmp?

Comment: coz i searched over and over and i can't find something to do the same job

Comment: well thx sir u have solved my second problem i was mistaken sorry

Answer (score 0):

you could use [memcmp](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstring/memcmp/)

But for c++ I would use such

```
 template <char a, char b, char c, char d>
    struct  NUMBER { 
        enum {
            value = a +
            (static_cast<uint32_t> (b) << 8) +
            (static_cast<uint32_t> (c) << 16) +
            (static_cast<uint32_t> (d) << 24)        };
    };

...

        uint32_t  data;
        fread(&data,sizeof(uint32_t),1,wav)

        if ( data !=  NUMBER<'R', 'I', 'F', 'F'>::value) //  "RIFF" 
            return -1; //Not RIFF
```